# How to boot my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini when wall charger is plugged

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, charging, boot, reboot

I am Developing an Android Application, here i want my phone to start booting automatically when the phone is plugged into any power outlet without hitting any power button.I found many solutions and tried all but unfortunately nothing worked for me

I edited the file found in '/system/bin/playlpm' with the following custom script that will boot the phone:

**Method #1**

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

**Method #2**

```
 #!/system/bin/sh/system/bin/reboot
```

**Method #3**

```
#!/system/bin/sh
su
/system/bin/reboot
```

but nothing worked for me. Please help me if somebody have any working solutions.

Comment: Did you set the permissions correctly? Also, you can make a script in your computer that launches it with `adb` when you connect the cable your phone to PC.